# API methods that return a single Item by id: unnecessary parameters to remove?

Tags: discussion

On methods that return a single item by id like the following:

> /badges/{id}
>   /answers/{id}
>   /questions/{id}
>   /comments/{id}
>   /users/{id}

is it correct to have these parameters on [Documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help)?

> - sort
> - order
> - min
> - max
> - fromdate
> - todate
> - page
> - pagesize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to have those parameters, because those are not only for single item.

They planned (may be already or partially work) to accept vectorized request like

```
/questions/1;2;3
```

above will return 3 items, and /answers , /comments , /users supposed to be same.

Comment: @systempuntoout - `fromdate` and `todate` restrict the returned objects by creation date.  The docs are wrong for the moment, nice catch.